# Drupal View Filter wole words

Tags: drupal-8

I have exposed an view filter in my drupal site and I have it return "Contains all words".
My problem is that it returns  and partially matched results.

For example if I search "part" I will get results for "Parthenon" and "Part of statue", while I want to get result only for "Part of statue".

In other words I don't want to get partially matched word like "Parthenon" but only the whole word matches for "part" as the "Part of statue".

How can I achive that?